Normal closure of $e_{12}$ in the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_1(p)\subset \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$
$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$For an odd prime $p$, let
$$\Gamma_1(p)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\in \SL_2(\mathbb{Z}):\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\equiv\begin{pmatrix}1 & * \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \mod (p)\right\}\subset \SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$$
be the congruence subgroup of level $p$. Let $e$ be the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Question: What is the normal closure of $\{e\}$ in $\Gamma_1(p)$?
For
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\in\Gamma_1(p),$$
we can see that
$$AeA^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1-ac & a^2 \\ -c^2 & 1+ac\end{pmatrix}$$
lies in the subgroup
$$\Gamma=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\in \SL_2(\mathbb{Z}):a\equiv d\equiv 1 \mod (p),\quad c\equiv 0 \mod \left(p^2\right)\right\}.$$
My guess is that the normal closure is exactly this subgroup $\Gamma$.
I have checked it for $p=3$, in which case $\Gamma$ is generated by
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},\ \begin{pmatrix}4 & -1 \\ 9 & -2\end{pmatrix},\ \begin{pmatrix}7 & -4 \\ 9 & -5\end{pmatrix}\right\},$$
where
$$\begin{pmatrix}4 & -1 \\ 9 & -2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 3 & 4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}4 & -1 \\ -3 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\begin{pmatrix}7 & -4 \\ 9 & -5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 1 \\ -3 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 3 & -2\end{pmatrix}$$
are conjugates of $e^{-1}$.
For $p=5$, I used Magma to obtain a set of generators of $\Gamma$, while not all of which are conjugates of $e^n$. However, it could still be possible that they are products of conjugates of $e^n$. I have no idea how it would be proven for general $p$.

A successive-approximation argument at least shows that the analogous normal closure with the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb Z_p$ in place of $\mathbb Z$ is what you'd like.  Do you happen to know that the normal closure contains some congruence subgroup?

My guess is that the normal closure of this matrix is an infinite-index subgroup.  The point here is that your subgroup of SL(2,Z) is the fundamental group of a finite cover of the modular curve, and I believe that once your prime p is large enough that cover will have positive genus.  Conjugates of your matrix e will correspond to loops around cusps since e is parabolic, so at best your normal closure is the subgroup generated by the cusps.  (sorry for the poor typesetting and explanation — I am writing this on a phone)

@AndyPutman You're absolutely correct! It turns out that the genus of the modular curve for $\Gamma$ is already nonzero when $p=7$ (it has genus 3). Thanks!

@LSpice I checked that the normal closure and $\Gamma$ do have the same image in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^n)$. It seems that the normal closure cannot be a congruence subgroup by Andy's argument when $p\ge7$.

@Max: Happy to help!

$\DeclareMathOperator{\SL}{SL} \newcommand\Z{\mathbb{Z}} \newcommand\bbH{\mathbb{H}}$
I'm at my office now, so I'll write a properly typeset version of my comment so this question will leave the "unanswered" queue.
Recall that the modular curve $Y$ is $\bbH^2/\SL_2(\Z)$.  Topologically, $Y$ is a once-punctured $2$-sphere with two orbifold points.  Any finite-index subgroup $\Gamma$ of $\SL_2(\Z)$ gives a finite orbifold cover $Y(\Gamma)$ of $Y$.  For your subgroup $\Gamma_1(p)$, write $Y_1(p)$ for $Y(\Gamma_1(p))$.
The space $Y_1(p)$ is topologically a punctured surface of finite type.  The punctures are the cusps.  Your element $e$ is a parabolic element of $\SL_2(\Z)$, so considered as an element of the fundamental group of $Y_1(p)$ it corresponds to a loop that is homotopic into one of the cusps.  The same is true for all conjugates of $e$.  It follows that the normal closure of $e$ in $\Gamma_1(p)$ is contained in the subgroup of the fundamental group of $Y_1(p)$ generated by loops around the cusps.  This is an infinite-index proper subgroup if $Y_1(p)$ has positive genus, which it does for $p \geq 7$.
